# position() != last() not working

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like:

```
<ast>
    <group>
        <Set>
            <location line="1" column="22" offset="22"/>
            <group>
                <Id value="foo">
                    <location line="1" column="31" offset="31"/>
                </Id>
            </group>
            <group>
                <Function>
                    <location line="1" column="22" offset="22"/>
                    <end-location line="1" column="49" offset="49"/>
                    <group>
                        <Id value="a">
                            <location line="1" column="35" offset="35"/>
                        </Id>
                        <Id value="b">
                            <location line="1" column="37" offset="37"/>
                        </Id>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <Return>
                            <location line="1" column="40" offset="40"/>
                            <Number value="0">
                                <location line="1" column="47" offset="47"/>
                            </Number>
                        </Return>
                    </group>
                </Function>
            </group>
        </Set>
        ...
    </group>
</ast>
```

which I process with this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="text()" /><!-- remove blanks -->

    <xsl:template match="Set[group[position()=1]/Id][group[position()=2]/Function]">
        <function-def>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="group[position()=1]/Id/@value" />
                <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="group[position()=2]/Function" />
                <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="group/Function/location" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="group/Function/end-location" />
        </function-def>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Function/group[position()=1]/Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

however the condition `position() != last()` on the last template is not working. Why?

The output renders as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<function-def name="foo(a,b,)">...
```

while it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<function-def name="foo(a,b)">...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, but not in the way you think....

In your first template, you have this `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="group[position()=2]/Function" />
```

But you have no template matching `Function`, and so XSLT's [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) kicks in, which is this...

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will select the `Group` elements, for which again there is no template. Now, when it does `<xsl:apply-templates/>` this will select all child nodes, which includes the empty text nodes used to indent the XML.

The problem is when you are testing `position() = last()` you are testing the position of the element in the set of all the child nodes that have been selected, which includes the text nodes. There is an empty text node after the last `id`, so `id` may be the last `id` element, but it is not the last child node.

One solution, is to tell XSLT to strip out empty text nodes, so that `id` then does become the last child node

```
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Alternatively, you can add a template matching `group`, and explicitly select only `id` nodes

```
<xsl:template match="Function/group[position()=1]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Id" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: oh! I thought the template with `match="Function/group[position()=1]/Id"` would match that `< xsl:apply-templates>` call...

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates />` is short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` which selects only the child nodes. So, the built-in templates then do processing for you behind-the-scenes.

Comment: thanks, `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` is exactly what I needed